# Big O Notation for two non-nested loops

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o, time-complexity

What would the Big O notation be for two for loops that aren't nested?

Example:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   System.out.println(i);
}

for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
   System.out.println(j);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Linear

```
O(n) + O(n) = 2*O(n) = O(n)
```

It does not matter how many non nested loops do you have (if this number is a constant and does not depends on `n`) the complexity would be linear and would equal to the maximum number of iterations in the loop.

Comment: So does this mean that when you have 2 nested loops `O(n^2)` you should split them in 2 single loops to obtain `O(n)` at the price of some memory?

Comment: What happens if the number of iterations in both loops are different? For example, first loop is iterated `m` times and second one is iterated `n` times where `n>>m`.

Comment: @santobedi if `m` is not a function of `n` then it does not matter.

Comment: @SalvadorDali What will be the time complexity in my case? `O(n)` or `O(m+n)` or `O(m)*O(n)` ? `m` are `n` are independent. `m` is not the function of `n`.

Comment: @santobedi `O(max(m,n))`

Answer (score 8):

Technically this algorithm still operates in O(n) time.

While the number of iterations increases by 2 for each increase in `n`, the time taken still increases at a **linear** rate, thus, in O(n) time.

Answer (score 5):

It would be O(2n) because you run n+n = 2n iterations.

O(2n) is essentially equivalent to O(n) as 2 is a constant.

Answer (score 4):

It will be `O(n)` + `O(n)` ==> Effectively `O(n)` since we don't keep constant values.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a scenario each loop runs up to n

So we can say the complexity of each for loop is `O(n)` as each loop will run n times.

So you specified these loops are not nested in a linear scenario for **first loop O(n)+ second loop O(n)+ third loop O(n)**  which will give you `3O(n)`.

Now as we are mostly concentrating on the variable part of the complexity we will exclude the constant part and will say it's `O(n)` for this scenario.

But in a practical scenario, I will suggest you keep in mind that the constant factor will also play a vital role so never exclude them.

For example, consider time complexity to find the smallest integer from an integer array anyone will say it's `O(n)` but to find second largest or smallest of the same array will be O(2n).

But most of the answers will be saying it's `O(n)` where actually ignoring the constant. 
Consider if the array is of 10 million size then that constant can't be ignored.